# ГЗsqlite sub-query remember result

Tags: sql, sqlite

I use sub-query at my select query, but as you can see at the example I execute the same sub-query with `type='jump'` two times to compare with different values. What is the best way to optimize this query? thanks

```
SELECT * FROM tableone WHERE ONE > 10 AND PAS != '' AND CMD = 'xxx' 
AND (SELECT COUNT() FROM tabletwo WHERE tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND TYPE='walk' AND TIMESTAMP > $last24hours) <= $walklimit 
AND (SELECT COUNT() FROM tabletwo WHERE tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND TYPE='jump' AND TIMESTAMP > $last24hours) <= $jumpslimit
AND (SELECT COUNT() FROM tabletwo WHERE tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND TYPE='jump' AND TIMESTAMP > $last24hours) <= $jumpsHOURlimit
LIMIT 1;
```

**UPDATE:** And what solution is better with `JOIN` or simple my with min() ?

Answer (score 2):

Your two subqueries are exactly the same.  The only difference is on the limit.  So, use `min()`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tableone t1
WHERE t1.ONE > 10 AND t1.PAS <> '' AND t1.CMD = 'xxx'  AND
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM tabletwo
       WHERE tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND TYPE = 'walk' AND TIMESTAMP > $last24hours
      ) <= $walklimit AND
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM tabletwo
       WHERE tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND TYPE='jump' AND TIMESTAMP > $last24hours
      ) <= min($jumpslimit, $jumpsHOURlimit)
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thank you. And what solution is better with `JOIN` or simple my with min() like @sgeddes suggest ?

Comment: You would need to try both solutions in your environment on your data to determine which is "better" by your criteria.  Both are viable solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you could also combine them into a single query using a `JOIN`, and then use `COUNT` with `CASE` to filter your results:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM tableone t1
   JOIN tabletwo t2 ON tabletwo.id = tableone.id AND t2.TIMESTAMP > $last24hours 
WHERE t1.ONE > 10 AND t1.PAS <> '' AND t1.CMD = 'xxx' 
GROUP BY t1.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.TYPE='walk' THEN 1 END) <= $walklimit
   AND COUNT(CASE WHEN t2.TYPE='jump' THEN 1 END) <= min($jumpslimit, $jumpsHOURlimit)
LIMIT 1;
```